# In a cell disable text that is already there but let the user add text to it

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Sorry if this have been asked already, I could not find any information about it.

I want to know if it's possible that once a user press a check box or a button the text in a specified cell become not editable but let the user add some text to it. It would mean that I don't want to disable the cell, just the text inside the cell.

If the question is not clear enough I can add some explanation or pictures to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can lock the cell then protect the sheet with some VBA code behind a button.

In order to add text to it, you would have to have another cell to input the new text, then another button to:

1. Unprotect the sheet
2. Append the update text to the locked cell
3. Reprotect the sheet

Comment: Not really what I was looking for. I guess this is not possible

Comment: In that case, no, I don't believe it's possible to lock part of a cell to protect it from editing. If that's not what you were looking for, then you'll need to clarify your question.

Comment: I will try using your answer then. I will give you some feedback once I have  it working. Thank you